# How to check the condition of a list during list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-3.6

Say I have a list of three words and I want to generate a list containing the characters in the word.

This can be achieved easily using for-loops or list-comprehension:

```
wordList = ["one", "two", "three"]
letterList = []

# Solution 1:

for word in wordList:
    for letter in word:
        letterList.append(letter)

# Solution 2:

letterList = [letter for word in wordList for letter in word]

print(letterList) # Prints: ['o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'o', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e']
```

However, when this problem is made more difficult, I am unable to find a solution using a list-comprehension.

For example, assume I want to generate the previous list, but I also want any duplicate characters to be removed.

I can do this using for-loops:

```
wordList = ["one", "two", "three"]
letterList = []

for word in wordList:
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letterList:
            letterList.append(letter)

print(letterList) # Prints: ['o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'h', 'r']
```

So, my question is: How do I check to see if an item is in the list being build during a list comprehension? Or put more simply: How do I do the above using list-comprehensions?

Comment: Yes, order is important.

Comment: List comprehensions allow you to only see the current element, _not_ the result accumulated so far. In other terms, a _list_ comprehension is a `map`, and you want a `reduce`. `OrderedDict` does deduplication for you, as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.6 dictionaries are ordered. Therefore you can use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> list({letter:None for word in wordList for letter in word}.keys())
['o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'h', 'r']
```

Starting from Python 3.7 the ordering will be guaranteed:

> python news:  @gvanrossum just pronounced that dicts are now guaranteed to retain insertion order. This is the end of a long journey.
>   [source](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/941709626545864704) (2017-12-15)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, this news is not even two weeks old.

Answer (score 3):

if order is not important just use a set comprehension

```
letter_set = {letter for word in wordList for letter in word}
```

if order is important it gets a bit grosser

```
seen = set()
letter_list = [x for word in wordlist for x in word if x not in seen and not seen.add(s)]
```

or using something like ordered dict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_list = OrderedDict.fromkeys(letter for word in wordList for letter in word).keys()
```

Comment: I see, so there is no simple "pythonic" way to do this. Would you recommend using for-loops to solve this problem?

Comment: the ordereddict is probably the most pythonic ... but a loop is quite acceptable for this type of use case as well

Answer (score 1):

You already got the set solution but here is one different solution :

Instead of using that list comprehension result , use that list comprehension for logic and append it to new list :

```
wordList = ["one", "two", "three"]
letterList = []
[letterList.append(letter) for word in wordList for letter in word if letter not in letterList]
print(letterList)
```

output:

```
['o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'h', 'r']
```